Discover all device aliases in VISA instrument
I have several Keysight DVMs attached to my computer.  Each may have multiple Aliases (user-defined names).  I am trying to discover all available Aliases for these instruments in software using the NI Visa library as provided by Keysight.
There is a function, viFindRsrc, which discovers instruments by type. Another function,  viParseRsrcEx, will return the 1st Alias for that instrument, but it will not return any other Aliases.  Is there a way to get the whole list?

"Each may have multiple Aliases" that does not seem correct, NI allows for 1 alias per instrument. Maybe you are intending to refer to more than just the alias? but other aspects as well such as model number, manufacture and serial number?

Keysight does allow multiple aliases - but no easy way to read them.  The NI defined VISA software only allows the first.

I received this note from Keysight:
"With IOLS 2024 and IOLS 2024 Update 1, the R&D team has developed and included the Keysight Instrument IO Service. This service has a "KIIS" server running in the background that provides a REST API to extract instrument information added into Keysight IO Libraries Suite's GUI -> Connection Expert. This means that if the customer has versions of IO Libraries Suite that are older than the 2024 version, the workaround below will not work. The customer can download these newer versions of IOLS from here: www.keysight.com/find/iosuite"
Basically, this is OK but not trivial.  I am going to rename all our DVMs uniquely ModelNo-SerialNo, and require our test software to use those IDs.
